# Are bonus attributes from base items automaticly added to the new item?

Tags: the-last-stand-dead-zone

When crafting new weapons or gear, a base item is sometimes required to craft the new item.

My question is, if my base item has a bonus range of + xx% and has a range of 28.
And my crafting item only has a range of 25, will the range of my base item be added automatically to the new item or will it be overwritten and end up with the range that is shown in the tool tip of the craft able item?

And if i use a crafting kit to extend the range even further, would that affect the stats of the base item or would it just add up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stats of a base item are completely overwritten when crafting a new item.
Only the stats that are shown in the tooltip + any chance of random improvement are possible.